# Problems getting log4j to write to sql server

Tags: java, sql-server, log4j

Having an issue getting log4j to write to sql server.  I have a java app, and sql server database.  I am able to write to file, but I would prefer to have the option to write to database.  My appender config is below.  When I try to call log4j.Info("test"); I get this error: "log4j:ERROR Failed to excute sql com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Could not find stored procedure 'Starting'.".  Any hints?

```
<appender name="DB" class="org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender">
        <param name="URL" value="jdbc:sqlserver://notarealserver;databaseName=notarealdatabase"/>
        <param name="driver" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
        <param name="user" value="notarealuser"/>
        <param name="password" value="notarealpassword"/>
        <param name="sql" value="insert into [dbo].[Log] values('%x', '%d','%C','%p','%m')"/>           <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"></layout>
    </appender>
```

Comment: Your config snippet does not use stored procedures, but the error message complains about a missing procedure. Are you sure your config is actually used?  Replace the URL with a dead server and see if the error message changes.

Comment: "Starting" was the test message I was trying to use. Thanks for the comment.  See below, there was an issue with the config file.  I needed to add a param named sql.  No clue how log4j took the message that I was trying to write, and tried to use it as a stored proc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the change that ended up working:

```
<appender name="DB" class="org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender">
    <param name="URL" value="jdbc:sqlserver://notarealserver;databaseName=notarealdatabase"/>
    <param name="driver" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
    <param name="user" value="notarealuser"/>
    <param name="password" value="notarealpassword"/>
    <param name="sql" value="insert into [dbo].[Log] values('%x', '%d','%C','%p','%m')"/>           
<layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"></layout>
</appender>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

`param name="sql" value="insert into [dbo].[Log] values('''%x''', 'getdate()','''%C''','''%p''','''%m''')`

Comment: Please add some formatting to this.  In its present state, this is painfully difficult to read.